# Can I purchase regular DDR3 RAM for my MAC (not from an iMac store?)

Tags: memory

I know that buying and installing RAM from a regular computer shop will be cheaper for me. I was just wondering if a Macbook Pro 17" early 2011 model uses specific 'Mac' DDR3 RAM or if I can get away with any DDR3 RAM?

Answer (score 4):

Generally in principle yes. You do not need to purchase expensive Apple memory.

However **you will need to check for each model** - the best thing is to go to a reputable memory supply company website which sells certified RAM and look up your model.

You can search for them online but here is a respected store (I have no affiliations with)

http://www.crucial.com

Answer (score 3):

Just be sure the memory you buy meets the specifications on [Apple's website](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1270#link6).

It's a very common type of  memory,  204-pin PC3-10600 DDR3 1333 MHz.

Answer (score 1):

Although memory chips conform to standards, there could be some minor variations. So it is advisable to buy from a seller who tests and guarantees compatibility of the RAM sticks for your Mac.

Two such stores in the U.S. that have served customers for a long time are [**OWC** - MacBook Pro 2011 RAM](http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/memory/Apple_MacBook_MacBook_Pro/Upgrade/DDR3_1333MHz_SDRAM) and [**Data Memory Systems** - MacBook Pro RAM](http://www.datamemorysystems.com/apple-macbook-pro-memory-upgrades/). These are usually cheaper than Crucial and offer good warranties.